# Why don't you see rigid PET extrusions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, plastics

So, I'm confused about something.  Rigid plastic extrusions for outdoor applications, such as twinwall greenhouse panels and the like, are most commonly polycarbonate.  They're next most common acrylic, although the consensus generally seems to be that they're not as good in most regards.  However, I find little to no evidence of rigid PET extrusions.  It seems to be used in either 1) PET film, or 2) molded PET... but nothing in-between.

Why is that?

PET seems like a far superior material to polycarbonate in these applications.  While its amorphous properties aren't impressive, when biaxially stressed (BoPET/Mylar - something that is achieved in extrusion), its tensile modulus is three times higher than polycarbonate, and its Young's modulus is nearly twice as high.  High strengths are not unusual among crystalline/oriented polymers, but what is unsual is that crystalline polymers are usually opaque; BoPET, given a proper heat treatment, retains excellent transparency and crystallinity by keeping the size of its crystals down to below the wavelength of visible light.  PET is cheaper than polycarbonate.  It's more UV stable than polycarbonate - one of the biggest problems of polycarbonate panels.  In all respects, it seems like it'd be a superior option.

So why isn't it used?  There must be something I'm missing...